# Is it mandatory to have Assests/Images/CSS present in SFMC?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, css, images, asset

We are about to kickoff with ipwarming.
we have emails ready, but the assets used in email creation are hosted on different server(not present in SFMC).
Is this something I should worry about, and upload all the assets within SFMC and update the URLs used within the emails before going with ipWarming?
Any prior experience/leads/document reference is appreciated.

Many Thanks!

Comment: Some companies store their images in their FTP servers, not in MC and I didn't hear anything bad while working with them. Hence, I don't think it would be a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with having the assets hosted outside of SFMC. There is a very small risk of affecting your sender reputation/deliverability, but this risk is negligible. I will however recommend having the assets hosted on a server supporting HTTPS, as using HTTP might show warnings to recipients, using older email clients. From an IP reputation perspective, using HTTPS will not necessarily have any positive impact on this.

Technically speaking, images are normally not even hosted on same infrastructure as the Marketing Cloud application. I.e. when you request SSL certificate for your SAP domain, you will need two certificates. One for images, another for all other URLs. This is due to the image assets being hosted on a CDN.

Brgds
Lukas

Comment: Agree with this.  Lots of folks use AWS since their assets are coming from a design team.   @Lukas is the risk level a documented metric, or is it just based on industry knowledge.   From my perspective, you definitely want to avoid using external assets if the domain reputation is poor (ie. you have 3rd party advertisers/partners and they spam like crazy).

Comment: Good question. I assume both domains are owned by the sender. E.g: marketing.example.com for your SAP domain and assets.example.com for the external source. I agree with you, having a lot of various domains with questionable reputation provide content into your emails is not recommended.